# Cordova - Es posible enviar notificaciones push, teniendo la app completamente cerrada, sin correr?

Tags: android, cordova

Estoy en pleno desarrollo de una app en Cordova (Android + iOS), y necesito hacer funcionar una serie de notificaciones push, enviadas desde el server. 
Estas deben funcionar cuando la app se encuentra corriendo en el background, o el dispositivo bloqueado, o directamente con la app sin correr completamente cerrada.
Existe posibilidad?

Answer (score 3):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta: Si es posible recibir notificaciones push cuando la aplicación esta cerrada(iOS y Android).

Actualmente **Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) no esta funcionando**, su reemplazo es [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), y pues con FCM las notificaciones push funcionan muy bien tanto en Android como en iOS.

El plugin que utilizo para las Notificaciones push con FCM es [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm)

Comment: Buenisimo, mas que interesante. Lo estare viendo.
Ahora otra pregunta: si o si es necesario emplear un "gestor" como era el GCM y el FCM?

Comment: Para android creo que no tienes otra alternativa que usar FCM, Para iOS quizá puedas utilizar directamente el servicio **Apple Push Notification service (APNS)**, Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si, es posible.

Es el servidor quien se encarga de enviar las notificaciones push a los dispositivos, debes tener en claro que para eso, en tu base de datos debe quedar guardado el `deviceToken` en el caso de iOS y el `regid` en el caso de Android para que, cuando se produzca una notificación sepa a quien debe enviarla.

Comment: Bien, buena data. 
Hoy tomo nota de todo y trato de hacerlo funcionar.